# Why does angular/cordova app suddenly reload?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

I have an angular/cordova app running in iOS. Sometimes the app just restarts. It is not closed, it just shows a blank page and then restarts. It's the same behaviour like calling `location.reload()`.

What can be the reasons for this behaviour? Memory issues? A known bug in angular/cordova (which I missed in my research)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your descriptio, the most probable cause sure seems to be a **memory leak** -- as the application runs, something keeps getting stored in memory and is never being cleared, leading to application's abrupt exit.

You should try opening a monitor tool of your operating system to track how much memory is being used at the moment, to see if it's steadily increasing (and if it drops after the application reloads itself).